# Can't connect to kafka docker container from another docker container

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I'm trying to connect to kafka docker container from another docker container. But it didn't connect.

There are the list of containers using for kafka messaging
[image]

Network **kafka-docker_default** has two containers **kafka-docker_zookeeper_1** and **kafka-docker_kafka0_1**
[image]

For running kafka and zookeeper I used docker-compose file:

```
version: '2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: "confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000

# This has three listeners you can experiment with. 
# BOB for internal traffic on the Docker network
# FRED for traffic from the Docker-host machine (`localhost`)
# ALICE for traffic from outside, reaching the Docker host on the DNS name `never-gonna-give-you-up`
# Use 
  kafka0:
    image: "confluentinc/cp-kafka"
    ports:
      - '9092:9092'
      - '29094:29094'
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    environment:
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: LISTENER_BOB://kafka0:29092,LISTENER_FRED://kafka0:9092,LISTENER_ALICE://kafka0:29094
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: LISTENER_BOB://kafka0:29092,LISTENER_FRED://localhost:9092,LISTENER_ALICE://never-gonna-give-you-up:29094
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: LISTENER_BOB:PLAINTEXT,LISTENER_FRED:PLAINTEXT,LISTENER_ALICE:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: LISTENER_BOB
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
```

Containers **dockercompose17138956372294708100_kafkatest.producer_1** and **dockercompose17138956372294708100_kafkatest.consumer_1** are for produce and consume messages. 
While container **dockercompose17138956372294708100_kafkatest.producer_1** is trying to connect to kafka cluster using bootstrap.servers parameter(localhost:9092 or never-gonna-give-you-up:29094) it showed error

```
%7|1569945335.015|BROKERFAIL|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:never-gonna-give-you-up:29094/bootstrap]: never-gonna-give-you-up:29094/bootstrap: failed: err: Local: Host resolution failure: (errno: Bad address)
%3|1569945335.015|FAIL|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:never-gonna-give-you-up:29094/bootstrap]: never-gonna-give-you-up:29094/bootstrap: Failed to resolve 'never-gonna-give-you-up:29094': Name or service not known (after 1656ms in state CONNECT)
%3|1569945335.015|ERROR|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:never-gonna-give-you-up:29094/bootstrap]: never-gonna-give-you-up:29094/bootstrap: Failed to resolve 'never-gonna-give-you-up:29094': Name or service not known (after 1656ms in state CONNECT)
%7|1569945335.015|STATE|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:never-gonna-give-you-up:29094/bootstrap]: never-gonna-give-you-up:29094/bootstrap: Broker changed state CONNECT -> DOWN
%3|1569945335.015|ERROR|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:never-gonna-give-you-up:29094/bootstrap]: 1/1 brokers are down
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> dockercompose17138956372294708100_kafkatest.producer_1 is trying to connect to kafka cluster using `bootstrap.servers` parameter(`localhost:9092` or `never-gonna-give-you-up:29094`)

From another Docker container, neither of those are correct.

1. `never-gonna-give-you-up` does not exist anywhere as a Hostname/DNS record in your Docker configuration. Based on the error, your external DNS server also doesn't know what that is
2. `localhost` refers to the Kafka client container, not your host, or the broker container.

According to your compose configuration, you need to connect to **`kafka0`** host/service, which is advertised on port **29092** for the `bootstrap.servers`

```
# BOB for internal traffic on the Docker network
KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: LISTENER_BOB://kafka0:29092
```

You should also probably remove LISTENER_ALICE because it isn't providing any useful connection details unless your host's *external hostname* is actually `never-gonna-give-you-up`

And you'll want to put your producer and consumer as part of your compose file

Comment: How is correct to set the Kafka  for internal and external connections?

Comment: What do you mean by internal? You've already got two listeners for that, and it doesn't look like you're trying to run code from inside the broker container... For external, you can run `hostname -f`, copy that output, then replace your "never gonna give you up" string with your actual hostname. From both the Docker host and external machines that use DNS, then they will communicate using the advertised hostname (you don't need the localhost listener if you use the external hostname)

Comment: @cricker_007 Internal means container connect to Kafka broker inside the same docker network. External means container connect to Kafka broker outside the docker network. Problem is container from another network can't connect to Kafka broker. I set 'KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://host:9092',  where is 'host' value of 'hostname' command. Question is why?

Comment: should producer container has the same network as kafka broker container?

Comment: Producer and consumer should be on the same network, yes. You should only connect to the hostname address if you are not running the kafka clients in other containers

Answer (score 3):

Please try this configuration:

```
version: '3'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
    ports:
      - "32181:32181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 32181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000

  kafka0:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    ports:
     - "9090:9090"
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    environment:
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:32181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: LISTENER_INTERNAL://kafka0:29090,LISTENER_EXTERNAL://localhost:9090
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: LISTENER_INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,LISTENER_EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: LISTENER_INTERNAL
      KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: "false"
```

With this configuration, if you connect from host to the broker's container, you use the IP `localhost:9090`. If you connect from other containers with the same network, you use `kafka0:29090`.

Comment: If I will connect from another container that doesn’t has the same network using the IP localhost:9090 it won’t be connect to the Kafka. How can I resolve it?

Comment: @Master This answer says if you're using another container, you'd use `kafka0:29090`, not localhost

Comment: Only if the docker network is the same for container use kafka0:29090. I asked what is the host to connect for container that is outside docker network, from another docker network or from another server?

Comment: @MasterMedia For the external service, the logic is the same. You can create the new advertised listener, then point to Kafka's address which the service can connect to. e.g: localhost:9090 becomes 10.0.12.20:9090. It depends too much on the external network that your Kafka is staying in.

Comment: Connection works, but then kafka advertises `localhost:9092` which causes connections to fail from other docker containers: `GroupCoordinator: localhost:9092: Connect to ipv4#127.0.0.1:9092 failed: Connection refused`. They can find the bootstrap server, but cannot connect afterwards...